# Cannot get document ready to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, particle-system, particles

I am having trouble getting a JQuery particle emitter plugin to work. I ran into this problem before, and it was because the jquery library and the script call for the particle.js file are being cued to load simultaneously and the emitter file obviously loads first. It then does not load effectively because the Jq lib has to load first to be able to process the '$' jquery call on line 3 of the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/particle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            var emitter = new particle_emitter({ size: 16, velocity: 50, decay:     2000, rate: 20 });
        emitter.start();
    });
    </script>
```

Any advice you can give me why the $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); isn't working to delay the load of the particle emitter call until after the Jq library has loaded would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `<script>` that loads jQuery before this code? Place it before.

Comment: @Raminson - no, decay looks like a valid option. http://www.erikfriend.com/jquery.particles/

Comment: You need to provide more code. Looks to me like you didn't include jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

First include jquery.js file. before particle.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

If you already have done then try to write jQuery(document).ready instead of $(document).ready

like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/particle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
            var emitter = new particle_emitter({ size: 16, velocity: 50, decay:     2000, rate: 20 }).start();
    });
</script>
```

note: I have moved the .start() to upper line just for shortening code.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. Works!!

Comment: if it resolved your problem then please accept the answer. i.e. click on tick sign

Comment: +'d for stating the obvious :) Non the less, what did solve the issue? (guessing the inclusion of the jquery.js beforehand)